# How to import data with double quotes in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, bulk-import

I have to import a text file with data which contains double quotes. Actually I have created a text file which contains aix commands and their explanation.

Now the commands contains double quotes. So using the regular approach of importing bulk data into SQL Server 2005 I am getting error.

My text file is like:

```
1,acledit "file",for changing the ACL(access control list) of a file
2,anacheck -ap,error analysing for Escala E + T
3,bsh,starts a born shell
4,cancel "print job number",for killing a print job
5,chgrp "group" "file",changes the group of a file
6,chitab "inittab statement",for disabling a statement of the /etc/inittab
7,chmod 0777 "file",gives everybody the right to read, write and execute the specified file
8,chown "user" "file",changes the owner of a file
9,compress -v "file",compresses a file
10,cplv,copies a logical volume (no mirroring)
```

Can someone plz guide me how to import this data as it is in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: a simple workaround for this to escape it by `find('"')` and `replace('"' , '""')` functionality in any text editor and import it, a proper way is to encode the `"` with some unicode while saving and decode it while retreiving.

Comment: Can u plz give a sample for how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BULK INSERT` with the `FIELDTERMINATOR` option

```
bulk insert [yourtablename] from 'yourfilepath' with (fieldterminator = ',')
```

Comment: Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 3 (Expl).

Comment: Your explanation field is too short for your data

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function Scalar Valued function like below to encode it to some other character and store it and decode it when you retrieve.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION EncodeString 
     (@data as varchar(max))
      RETURNS varchar(max)AS 
     BEGIN
        DECLARE @result as varchar (max)
        SELECT @result = REPLACE(@data , '"','_')
        RETURN @result
      END
```

The above function returns `1,acledit _file_,for changing the ACL(access control list) of a file` for your input number 1. you can use any other ASCII/unicode instead of `_` , additionally you need to write decode function to use in retrieval and searching functioanlity. Hope this shall help.